# User Registration and Login in .NET Core, where does IdentityServer come in?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have read on IdentityServer 4 and have an understanding of what it tries to do, but I am still struggling to understand how it fits with what I am trying to do.

Here's my situation.

[image: architecture]

I want to build a .NET Core API that would power an `x` number of clients, all I could think of for now is a ReactJS app and a native mobile app.

On the .NET Core API, I can expose end-points for user registration and user login and I can add `[Authorize]` attribute to endpoints that I want to be secured, do I even need IdentityServer 4 here?

If you could shed some light on the matter, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You can accomplish your stated aim using just Identity Core

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to think of IdentityServer as "distributed auth", as that's basically all it is. Whereas with something like Identity, you'd directly check the user's credentials at the database, read their roles, claims, etc. from the database, with IdentityServer, that all basically happens via an API layer.

In other words, you simply set up an app with IdentityServer, which acts as your authentication and authorization gateway, and then all your other apps "hook" into this via one of the available auth schemes. For an API, that'd be something like a bearer token. For a mobile app, you'd likely use hybrid auth/OpenID Connect. Third-party/loosely related sites would use an OAuth workflow.

Regardless of the scheme, IdentityServer simply returns a principal that your other apps will utilize just as if they had authenticated directly via something like Identity.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt, but when I have a .NET Core API, those things you mentioned, such as checking user creds, roles ..etc > it again all happens through the API, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than type out an introduction to OpenID Connect here it's probably best to direct you to this nice presentation by the authors of IdentityServer4:

https://vimeo.com/113604459

That should hopefully explain how it would fit into your topology.

Comment: Thank you @mackie, I'll have a listen of that :)